# Is there a method to tell when the Ace Editor has finished rendering it's content?

Tags: ace-editor

Is there an event that describes when Ace Editor has finished syntax highlighting it's contents?

What I'm doing now is timing how long it takes to run this call:

```
var theBeforeTimes = getTimer();
var aceEditor = ace.edit("myEditor");
//setAllOptionsOn(aceEditor);
//aceEditor.addListener("everythingsDone", doneHandler);
aceEditor.setValue(myCode);
console.log(getTimer()-theBeforeTimes);
```

I'm trying different options and I want to test the performance in each mode. What I mean is, I want to time how long it takes to render without any extensions running and time how long it takes with ALL extensions running. That way if it is slow I can tell or show the user how long it is with and without their selected extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering is done from `requestAnimationFrame` callback, it's not affected much by extensions.
Tokenization is separate from rendering and is done from timeout at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.0/lib/ace/background_tokenizer.js#L64

if you want to measure how fast a mode can tokenize whole document use

```
function measure(editor) {
    var session = editor.session;
    // reset cache
    session.bgTokenizer.lines.length = session.bgTokenizer.states.length = 0
    var l = session.getLength()
    var t=performance.now()
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) session.getTokens(i)
    return performance.now()-t
}
measure(editor)
```

Comment: Will this measure how long it takes from keypress to return of control? What I mean is if I have a document of 1000000 lines and the user presses a key, how long does it take before the editor is done with it's work (if document is a million lines and beach ball shows up) and user can type the next key? Will this measure the latency?

Comment: Ace doesn't highlight full document between keypress and render.
For  what you want you need to use chrome devtools profiler, or timeline.

Comment: Is the editor locked at a specific update interval? Is there a way to cause it to call requestAnimationFrame() at a more shorter interval?

Comment: It calls requestAnimationFrame when it gets an event from the browser. If you see some specific problem, please describe it instead of asking questions without context.

Comment: I found this recently, https://pavelfatin.com/typing-with-pleasure/, and I was getting mixed results. Using the same test I was getting different latency values when run on Safari compared to Firefox; almost 2x difference. So I've been trying to find the reason why.

Comment: Safari is much better optimized on mac than firefox, did you try measuring the same thing for textarea, or other editors on both browsers?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that measurement is the same for all text inputs. My results are 30ms on Safari and 55ms on Firefox. Is this something that Mozilla would be able look into?

Comment: You can try reporting an issue on bugzilla, if you think that difference is noticeable while typing.